# Retrieve a file in a directory that matches a filename pattern

Tags: java, file, io

I need to retrieve a file in a given directory that matches a specific filename. In case multiple files are found, I will issue an error. How can I do this in java?

Below is the example: (these are parameters)
Directory = C:\files
Filename = "SampleFileEXT.csv"

The file inside the directory is assumed to have filename suffix with timestamp. So i need to get the "SampleFileEXT20150811090028197.csv"

Comment: [`File#listFiles(FileFilter)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles(java.io.FileFilter)) or [Finding Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html)

Comment: Similar to how would you do it in command prompt. Get list of all files in dir and do a pattern match. If multiple matches issues error else otherwise. The only question is timestamp is that some user input?

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj, timestamp is not a user input. This is already part of the filename. How can I do a pattern match? Do you have an example?

Comment: use regex. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

The question is old. But the solution may be helpful for other readers.

```
public List<File> getFiles(String location, final String type) {

    File folder = new File(location);
    FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.toLowerCase().startsWith(type.toLowerCase());
        }
    };
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(filter);
    return Arrays.asList(listOfFiles);
}
```

You can then play with return value to get the file if it returns single file or throw error if it returns zero or multiple files.